# AWS Cloudformation Codecommit S3 400 Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit

I have created a cloudformation template which creates a new repo in codecommit,Also it need to pull the source.zip from S3 and copy it to the repo. but while running the template i see 400 bad request.

[image: Cloudformation Stack]

CF template:

```
 AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: my First code commit CF template

Parameters:
  DemoBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket in which you have code
    Default: jaivijaycccf
  DemoKey:
    Type: String
    Description: key of zipped code
    Default: demo.zip

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::CodeCommit::Repository
    Properties: 
      RepositoryName: HelloWorldApp
      RepositoryDescription: This is a repository for my project with code from MySourceCodeBucket
      Code:
        BranchName: development
        S3:
          Bucket: !Ref DemoBucket
          Key: !Ref DemoKey
          ObjectVersion: 1
```

Comment: Is your S3 bucket set up to use versioning? What happens if you exclude the `ObjectVersion: 1` property?

Comment: Yes, Removing Version worked for me. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 1):

If the S3 bucket that is storing the source code does not use Object Versioning then providing the ObjectVersion paramater to the Cloudformation template will cause it to fail.
Removing the unnecessary parameter will fix the problem.

I'm adding this as an answer after you've confirmed that you aren't using object versioning.